# Get only one parameter from HTTP GET-Request (Angular 11)

Tags: angular

i want to get only one parameter of an HTTP Get-Request.

The (short) database is the following:

```
{
  "status": "0",
  "id": 1
}
```

and i want to save "status" in a new variable.

My code in the components.ts is the following:

```
  dataSource:Notifications[] = null;
....
 this.httpClient.get<Notifications[]>('http://localhost:1000/xxx/xxx/display/notification/1')
    .subscribe(val => 
      {
        console.log(val);
        this.dataSource = val;  
      }, 
      err => {
      });
```

So if i want to display all data in a table it works fine. But i want to only get the "status" of id = 1 save in a new variable.
How am i manage to do it?

**EDIT**:

my Notification.ts:

```
export interface Notification {
    ID: number,
    status: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few different methods to achieve your goal. You can e.g. use `map` operator to get one element:

```
.get(...).pipe(
    map(data => data.find(el => el.id === 1))
).subscribe(...
```

It won't work if there won't be an element with `id=1` in your array.

Second one is to assign this value in the same way as in map method:

```
.subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val);
    this.dataSource = val.find(el => el.id === 1);   
}
```

Then you just need to access property of your found object, e.g. `this.dataSource.status`. It depends what you want to achieve, if you want to leave your `dataSource` as it was before, you can create new class property and just assign value inside callback of your subscribe method:

beginning of class:

```
public status = '';
```

Inside subscribe:

```
this.dataSource = val;
const dataItem = val.find(el => el.id === 1);
this.status = dataItem ? dataItem.status : '';
```

Comment: sorry for asking, but what is el in your example?

Comment: @KaidoSama it is shorten for `element`, I've just named an element to iterate through array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one status, your dataSource should not be of type Notifications[]. It should be a string.

You'd just map the Observable response to get status as in,

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.httpClient.get<Notifications[]>('http://localhost:1000/xxx/xxx/display/notification/1')
    .pipe(map(val => val.status))
    .subscribe(val => 
      {
        console.log(val);
        this.dataSource = val;  
      }, 
      err => {
      });
```

If you wanted an array of status but worded your question wrong, you'd do this instead,

```
import { map, switchMap, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';


this.httpClient.get<Notifications[]>('http://localhost:1000/xxx/xxx/display/notification/1')
    .pipe(switchMap(val => val), map(item => item.status), toArray())
    .subscribe(val => 
      {
        console.log(val);
        this.dataSource = val;  
      }, 
      err => {
      });
```

What's happening here is the switchMap is streaming the array of response into a single value at a time and we map that single Notification value to get only status out of it and finally we zip it up back into an array of status.

Comment: when i copy the first code part from you i got this : error TS2339: Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Notification[]'. And i only want to get that exact status where id is = 1

Comment: You are passing 1 as a pathvariable in your REST endpoint. Does it not return just a single notification? If your server is sending an array of Notification Types and you want to get the one with id: 1, use the second solution. Just have a filter(val => val.id === 1) between switchMap() and map()

Comment: sorry for asking:  i pasted in following:  dataSource:Notification[] = null;
  getrequest(){
    this.httpClient.get<Notification[]>('http://localhost:1000/xxx/xxx/display/notification/1')
    .pipe(switchMap(val => val.id === 1), map(item => item.status), toArray())
    .subscribe(val => 
      {
        console.log(val);
        this.dataSource = val;  
      }, 
      err => {
      });
  } but get an error TS2339: Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Notification[]'.
.pipe(map(val => val.status)) for val.id === 1
                            ~~~~~~

Comment: You got it wrong, switchMap(val => val), filter(val => val.status === 1), map(val => val.status), toArray() is the right way to go